# Nested classes vs Separate class files

Tags: java, file, class, nested, subclass

In java at least, my compiler won't let me put two (or more) separate classes in a single class file. It forces me to create multiple files in the same package. I understand why this is, and I agree with this principle. However, I've realized that I could just as easily nest the classes and contain the entire program (excluding imported libraries) in a single file. I would imagine that this would be frowned upon, but I don't understand why. What are the dangers and disadvantages of nesting class as opposed to the standard system (outside of the severe loss in organization and neatness)?

Comment: severe loss in organization and neatness

Comment: What are the advantages in nesting everything?

Comment: You can store your entire program (and dependencies if you want) in a single file, but it would be a `.jar` file, not a `.java` file or a `.class` file.

Comment: You're allowed to put as many top-level classes in one source file as you want, as long as there is only one *public* class in the file (and the file has to have the name of that public class with the extension `.java`). The other classes will have to be package-only-scope classes, as you're not allowed to have private classes at top-level.

Comment: What are the advantages of organizing things instead of throwing them all in the same box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you keep everything in the same file, you lose packages and the private keyword does no longer have any meaning.

Given that most Java projects will be opened in an IDE that presents different classes as different tabs, you can have more that one cursor in the program.

Why would you have everything in the same file?